# Hide copy define Menucontroller in UIWebView IOS-5?

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I was able to hide the UImenucontroller when selecting the word in UIWebview using the below code in IOS-4.

```
- (BOOL) canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender {
    UIMenuController *menuController = [UIMenuController sharedMenuController];

    if (menuController) {
        [UIMenuController sharedMenuController].menuVisible = NO;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

But now this code is not working in IOS-5.

I need to select the text without this menucontroller. So i cannot control it using css and javascript. @selector(copy:) is also not working.
Please Update your answer.

Thanks,

Comment: Why are you checking if menuController is nil? You can safely send a message to a nil object.

Comment: Why are you calling `sharedMenuController` twice? If you're going to get a pointer to the menu controller, and then check that pointer, I'd think you'd then *use* that pointer.

Comment: It'd help if you could be more explicit about the failure than "not working." All those methods (`canPerformAction:withSender:`, `sharedMenuController`, and `menuVisible`) are supported back to iOS 3, according to [the docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIResponderStandardEditActions_Protocol/UIResponderStandardEditActions.html#//apple_ref/occ/cat/UIResponderStandardEditActions), and none are marked as deprecated.